# Did China ever try to change regimes in any country?

Tags: china, regime-change

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regime_change#:%7E:text=Regime%20change%20is%20the%20forcible,%2C%20administrative%20apparatus%2C%20or%20bureaucracy.) -

> Regime change is the forcible or coerced replacement of one government regime with another. Regime change may replace all or part of the state's most critical leadership system, administrative apparatus, or bureaucracy.

Did China ever try to change regimes in any country successfully or unsuccessfully?

Comment: Note that the examples in the Wikipedia link that you provided for the United States include several examples of regime change that were also annexations, including the aforementioned example of Hawai'i, along with Texas, California, and American Samoa.

Comment: @Obie2.0, that list was not created by me.

Comment: Be that as it may, the list is correct. Regime change, as typically defined, is a component of most if not all annexations. Obviously your question can use a more specific definition instead....

Comment: Should be on History.SE.

Comment: @Allure The People's Republic of China actively claims that they have never tried to engage in regime change.

Comment: @Davidw it's still a question about the history of the PRC and so should be on the History SE.

Comment: Do suporting anticolonial movement count as regime change?

Comment: @convert, check the definition from Wikipedia.

Comment: @Davidw: it would be interesting to see some statements/quotes in that regard. I know they keep trumpeting "non-interference in internal affairs", which actually is somewhat more true of the post-Deng leadership, including their "zero enemies" policy in the Middle East (check out their investments in Israel) but I'm not sure I've seen them declare they never did any regime change.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just the most obvious ones:

- China openly fought on North Korea's side. NK tried to conquer all of Korea, so arguably do a "regime change" in the South. (I don't know if they supported the initial NK attack though, with logistics. There is a [now declassified] 1949 [Soviet cable](https://digitalarchive.wilsoncenter.org/document/121178) that China was willing to send troops even then, with somewhat amusing/frank talk like "we can through a few Chinese soldiers over to you; they are all black-[haired], no one will make them out, added Mao Zedong". Another [telegram of 1950](https://digitalarchive.wilsoncenter.org/document/115976) from Stalin to Mao ostensibly left the date of the attack ["reunification"] to be decided by the Chinese and North Koreans together.)
- China supported Pol Pot who carried out a revolution in Cambodia.
- China supported the Viet Minh against the French (so "regime change" in the North of Vietnam), but fearing a repeat of Korea, tried to dissuade the Vietnamese from the Soviet inspired tactics like the Tet offensive in the South.
- China had a good cooperation in Laos with the North Vietnamese, both supporting the Pathet Lao armed struggle until 1968 or so, when the Sino-Soviet split made Laos more of a Vietnamese thing.

According to [Lovell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_Lovell)'s book *Maoism*, China sponsored at least with training in insurgency some 20,000 people in no less than 19 African revolutionary movements, at a cost of some $170 to $220 million over 20 years (this data is based on a [Chinese source](https://julac.hosted.exlibrisgroup.com/primo-explore/fulldisplay?vid=CUHK&docid=CUHK_IZ21817347860003407&lang=en_US&context=L)), the most notable in terms of success these movements being ZANU in Zimbabwe.

Comment: With the Korean War, China joined well after NK was pushed out of the South and the reasons for joining the war were defensive, so I don’t think it qualifies as regime change.

Comment: @HHuang: Possibly. But while I know for a fact that China (unlike the USSR) dissuaded the Tet offensive, which is why didn't say anything about Vietnam (although I probably should, since they supported the Viet Minh against the French), it's not clear to me China didn't logistically support the NK initial attack.

Answer (score 28):

China conquered and changed the regime in Tibet [in 1950](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibet#From_1950_to_present).

Comment: It is doubtful whether Tibet qualified as a country at the time of the PLA occupation in 1950. It had received very limited international recognition since the Xinhai revolution, probably only from Mongolia, arguably from the United Kingdom when it signed the Simla Accord. If you are willing to accept Tibet as an answer, then Mengkukuo, Manchukuo and the various territories controlled by warlords such as Yan Xishan would also be valid examples.

Comment: @CharlieEvans it doesn't have to be a country for someone to conquer it. China has certainly used the world's unwillingness to accept Tibet et al as answer (to paraphrase you) in spreading their expansive view of what constitutes China.

Comment: @tobi_s Indeed, but the title of the question is "Did China ever try to change regimes in any *country*" and in the body of the question "Did China ever try to change regimes in any *country* successfully or unsuccessfully?" (emphasis mine) so I stand by pointing out that the example given in this answer probably wasn't a country.

Comment: @CharlieEvans yeah, I was trying to emphasize that using a definition of "country" as "an entity recognized internationally as a country" would be a very limited way of interpreting this question. After all, the PRC itself wasn't recognized as a country before 1971 (and Taiwan would be up for the taking since then).

Comment: @tobi_s It is not a limited way of interpreting the question, any answer must make an explicit or implicit interpretation of what a country is. The constitutive idea that countries are demarcated by international recognition is very much mainstream. UNGA Resolution 2758, which you seem to allude to by referencing 1971, concerned which government had the right to represent China at the UN, not whether or not China was a country. In any case, my primary contention was not that this answer is wrong *per se* but rather that it lacks both exposition and range.

Comment: @CharlieEvans If we take your definitions, then China invading Taiwan and forcing regime change would not qualify as an answer as you are implying that Taiwan is not a country. I agree with you on the issue of the answer being a bit curt, and I agree with you that clear definitions are useful. Those are not ends in themselves. The fact that borders in Asia were still being drawn after WW2 (are still being drawn) certainly has relevance to this question. 27 upvotes seem to agree. I don't think we have much left to talk about, and comments are not for extended conversation, so I will stop here.

Comment: @tobi_s Taiwan has much more international recognition than Tibet ever had, but even so if the PLA *had* occupied Taiwan it wouldn't have been a particularly good answer to this question, considering that there are much more clear cut examples. The fact that this answer received 27 upvotes in no way repudiates my analysis. It is true that comments are not for extended discussion, which is all the more reason to exercise restraint in commenting on comments, rather than the answer.

Comment: @CharlieEvans You're assuming that the OP was choosing their words so carefully that they considered the distinction between countries and other entities. It's likely that they assumed anything with a regime that could be changed would necessarily be a country.

Comment: @Barmar I am making no such assumption. I am simply answering the question that the OP asked. As they offered minimal further explanation, I see no basis for speculation as to their likely assumptions, one way or another.

Answer (score 10):

This of course depends on what you mean by "China", "try", "regime change", and "country". The CCP successfully engaged in a regime change of mainland China. This regime change included regions that arguably have distinct national identity, such as Tibet, Manchuria, Inner Mongolia, and Xinjiang. They supported the successful regime change of Korea from part of the Japanese empire, and supported the attempted regime change of South Korea to being ruled by the communist North. They supported the successful regime change of Vietnam from the Republic of Vietnam, and the successful regime change of Cambodia, which led to the unsuccessful attempt of regime change (or, at least, attack on) communist Vietnam. They annexed Hong Kong, and arguably have abrogated their agreement regarding its autonomy. They have been trying for decades to effect regime change of Taiwan.

Answer (score 2):

This might be stretching the definition of "regime change" and "country" `*`, but China has clearly engaged in coercive methods to install *just exactly the government it wants* in Hong Kong and this has been getting more pronounced over time.

Dissent is not tolerated and candidates for the "elections" need to be Beijing-approved.

While it is tempting to look at the US's, and Russia's, activities in this domain, China has been very far from benign, as other answers have also detailed.

`*` the original promise was "one country/two systems".  The second part certainly has not been delivered on.

Comment: More or less by its own admission, this answer doesn't actually answer the question. Hong Kong is not, and has never been, a country and the influence that the Chinese central government has exerted on Hong Kong does not meet the threshold for "regime change", as that term is commonly understood. Finally, contrary to the assertion in this answer, there clearly are "two systems", even if many people are dissatisfied with the system in Hong Kong.

Comment: Hong Kong is not a country by any definition and the comment about US and Russia is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Hong Kong is part of China, so you could say this is China imposing regime change on itself.